# Australian fantasy novel where a wizard's nephew is kidnapped by a family whose son is cursed

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a fantasy novel about a wizard whose nephew is kidnapped by a family. The son in the family is cursed and they need the wizard's nephew because something about him can break the curse. The wizard goes to save his nephew, but ends up taking the cursed son with them when they escape. The wizard then starts to fall in love with the cursed son (who is a grown man) and then has to make a difficult decision about whether or not to return the cursed son to his family. One of the main characters might have been named Cassius or something beginning with a "C". The only other thing I remember is that the writer was an Australian woman.

Comment: Is this a male wizard (e.g. the novel is has gay characters)?

Comment: Possibly one of these authors; https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/enu2vz/female_authors_in_the_australian_fantasy_market_a/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Paper book or e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Yes, the wizard was a male wizard (I'm pretty sure the wizard was either gay or bisexual). I found the book in the library in the year 2020 and I am positive it was written after 2000. Definitely a paper book. I don't recall much about the cover art except that it was definitely not black or a dark-colored jacket.

Comment: I've just perused the works of every Australian female fantasy writer I know of: Sara Douglass, Kate Forsyth, Cecilia Dart-Thornton, Juliet Marillier and Traci Harding. No luck.

Comment: Thanks, Moriarty. I appreciate your efforts. It might be a while before I find the book. I'll keep trying though.